# Docker compose interpreter in pycharm dies after being idle for a short time

Tags: python, docker, pycharm

I've got a docker compose interprter in pycharm.  It looks like this:

[image]

After a period of idleness, the interpreter dies.  It looks like this:

[image]

The containers are still there, and up:

[image]

Here is the relevant part of `docker_compose.yml`:

```
services:

  pykernel:
    tty: true
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    expose:
      - "5000"
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
```

I'm using pycharm 2023.1.1.  Docker is running on WSL, pycharm on windows.  This problem started after upgrading from the 2021 version (don't remember which).

**Why is my interpreter dying?**